# 2D collsion detection in arc

Tags: c++, math

I need to implement 2D collision detection by arc. I have player(black dot) and enemies(red dots). Player can attack in any direction and his hit area is 120 degrees(green lines show it) and certain radius(black curve).

[image: My art]

How to achieve this detection?

I have done code where angle is calculated between player and enemy but i cant understand how to use player's direction vector to check if it inside arc.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the curve and the length of the green lines?

Comment: green lines just show the angle. Curve is actual radius

Comment: Yes, but player can rotate this arc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the angle to the enemy and the distance away they are. Use this to check if they are in range.

The problem is simple if the area where a square since you are using Cartesian coordinates so by converting to radial coordinates, this problem becomes simple too.

**With new information**

- Vector A is the player's direction vector.
- Calculate a vector B from the enemy to the player.

Check the length of vector B isn't too long.

Then angle between the vectors is given by: acos(|A.B| / |A||B|)

If the angle is less than 60 degrees (half the 120) then the enemy is in range.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the player must have a direction, a 2D vector for example. In simple it's angle with the first green line = it's angle with the other green line.

You should perform two checks:

1. Check if the distance between the enemy and the player is less than the radius, if not, move to the next enemy, if yes then
2. Draw a virtual line between the player and the enemy and calculate the angle between this line and the the direction of the player, if it's less than the half of hit-area-angle (in your example, if it's less than 60) then the player CAN hit the enemy, if not move to the next one.

That should be enough as an idea, hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have unit-length vector pointing "forward". And let's say you have unit length vector pointing to potential target. If target is within ark, then;

`dot(forwardVector, targetVector) >= cosf(arcAngle/2)`.

If vectors aren't unit length, it won't work, of course. That checks if the target is within required angle.

Checking if it is within required distance is trivial and is pretty much `squaredLength(targetPosition - playerPosition) <= arkDistance*arkDistance` where squaredLength is `dot(vector, vector)`.